# Bold, vivid family

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, wordplay, anagram, acrostic

> I remember organising the colours of the rainbow in columns. In the way that I did, I could create the word **RAINBOW** from certain letters in each word, indicated by the columns they were each placed in. However, I forgot how it worked, and I can only remember four colours in each of their position — I don't know which position each of the other three colours belong to. I have marked those remaining positions that the colours need to go in, with hyphens of a quantity matching to the number of letters in its neighbouring colour of the same column.
>
> ```
>                         Red        ------       Green
>                         Indigo     Orange       -----
>                         ------
> ```

Which colour of the remaining three goes in which position to achieve the word **RAINBOW** in the way previously described?

---

No hints! You have been given more than one ;)

Comment: Already an upvote? Jeez, how fast do you guys read?!

Comment: This is a bit more difficult for us non-native English speakers, who haven't been indoctrinated into believing that there are only a small integer number of distinct colours in the continuous spectrum of visible light. :-)

Comment: @Bass Oh, sorry! I meant the seven main clearly-clear-and-visible colours of the rainbow (ROYGBIV, as I've been taught). I don't mean to *indoctrinate*... I think that might be a strong word... but I guess this riddle can be externally *misleading*, I would say, hence I apologise to the non-native English speakers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feels a bit underdetermined to me, probably meaning that I'm missing some hidden hints that nail things down further. But here's one thing we can do, which meets the *explicitly given* requirements:

> ```
> Red    viOlet greeN
> Indigo orAnge yelloW
> Blue
> ```

where we take

> the *first* letter of things in the left column, the *third* letter of things in the middle column, and the *last* letter of things in the right column, yielding RIB/OA/NW which anagrams to RAINBOW.

Comment: Superb answer, Gareth! Once again, you become the fox of all riddles — quick, clever and sneaky, too, having ninjaed someone else's answer! Hahah, I will give the tick to you, but also some credit to @DqwertyC. If you get many more upvotes than their answer, I'll probably award them a $50$ rep bounty. You are the moderator, so I ask you first if that seems fair :)

Comment: Yeah, there is another hint you missed, but you'll probably figure it out. I can vote again in at least $6$ hours from now, incidentally.

Comment: In my capacity as moderator, I hereby declare that you should feel free to vote, accept, offer bounties, and accept bounties in whatever way seems most reasonable to you.

Comment: Congratulations, Gareth! $(+1)\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 7):

The colors are

> `Red     Violet  Green`
>  `Indigo  Orange  Yellow`
>  `Blue`

The rules are

> First letter from colors in the first column, third letter from colors in the middle column, and last letter from colors in the last column.

Comment: Ha! Ninjaed you by 22 seconds.

Comment: (The fact that we ended up with the same answer makes me think maybe it's less underdetermined than I feared.)

Comment: And you ninjaed me to making the inverse comment on your own answer!

Comment: I'm just too quick for you. Sorry!

Comment: You and @GarethMcCaughan I swear how do you find these so quickly?! I spent about $40$ minutes trying to come up with a reasonably difficult puzzle which I thought was this, and then you guys solve it in what, $40$ seconds??? xD